# Compiling C++ with Scons and Emscripten

Tags: c++, build, scons, emscripten

I want to build a simple HelloWorld program for web using the Scons build system with emscripten.

I have this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>

void loop()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    emscripten_set_main_loop(loop, -1, false);
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it with emscripten directy with:

```
emcc main.cpp -o Test.html
```

It generates correctly the web assembly build with the html, however what I would like to do is to compile it with Scons and generating the same output that emscripten generates.

I have this Sconstruct scons script:

```
environmentRoot = Environment()
environmentRoot.Program("Test", ["main.cpp"])
```

The problem is that I do not know how can I tell scons to use emscripten and generate the web assembly files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do one of two things.

1. Use a SCons tool for an already defined toolchain (perhaps gcc) and modify the Environment() variables which affect the generated command lines.

Something like this might work:

```
env=Environment(tools=['gcc','gnulink'], CC='emcc', PROGSUFFIX='.html')
```

2. Create a new SCons tool and associated Builder()'s. See: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-writing

Either way you'll need more than beginner knowledge of SCons and would be well served to read the users guide (and parts of the manpage)
https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

Comment: emscripten has some scons support, would definitely start there - there appears to be a tool which kind of does what @bdbaddog suggests - it expects to use an existing tool(chain) specification, but then sets up a bunch of variables and patches in the emscripten tools.  See https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/tools/scons/site_scons/site_tools/emscripten

Comment: Trying both solutions, it generates the same errror: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

But I have installed python 3.10.7 and set its path to the system, so I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: Need way more information than your error message to be able to help you. Can you update your question with whatever your SConstruct is now?

Comment: A little investigation... TLDR: ask at the emscripten project, they should be able to help, or there will be docs.  I find if you set up emsdk by running the startup script, you'll have access in your path to a provided script `emscons.py` which is intended to serve as a wrapper for calling scons with the right things set. But I didn't find how to use it - so asking for help at that project would seem to be the way to go.[UPATE -  think I didn't get the emsdk setup complete]